# Solving: $\ddot{y}+\dot{y}+\frac{1}{x}y=\frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve this equation as per the title

$$\ddot{y}+\dot{y}+\frac{1}{x}y=\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Here is my solution process, I really just want to know if this is the most general solution, if not why?

$$\dot{y}+\frac{1}{x}y=\frac{1}{x^2}-\ddot{y}$$

$$\dot{y}+\frac{1}{x}y=-\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{1}{x}+\dot{y}]$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}[yx]=-x\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{1}{x}+\dot{y}]$$

$$\int\frac{d}{dx}[yx]\,dx=-\int x\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{1}{x}+\dot{y}]\,dx$$

$$yx=-1-x\dot{y}+\int\frac{1}{x}+\dot{y}\,dx$$

$$y(x-1)=-1-x\dot{y}+\ln(x)+C$$

$$\dot{y}+(1-\frac{1}{x})y=\frac{C}{x}+\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}[y\frac{e^x}{x}]=\frac{Ce^x}{x^2}+\frac{e^x\ln(x)}{x^2}$$

And so we have

$$y=xe^{-x}\int\frac{Ce^x}{x^2}+\frac{e^x\ln(x)}{x^2}\,dx$$

I’m honestly satisfied with the integral solution because of how the log one turns out when integrated, but my question still stands, is this solution the most general?

Comment: You could simplify the homogeneous part with $\int \frac{c_{1} \cdot e^{-x}}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x = C_{1} \cdot \Gamma\left( -1,\, -x \right) + c_{2}
$ (with the incomplete gamma function) or with $\int \frac{c_{1} \cdot e^{-x}}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x = C_{1} \cdot \left( \operatorname{Ei}\left( x \right) - \frac{e^x}{x} \right) + c_{2}$ as you can see [here](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=C_1%20e%5Ex%2Fx%5E2/) (the [exponential integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html)).

Answer (score 1):

##### Lost Solutions

I would say that this is already the most general solution as I don't see any step where you lose a solution for $x > 0$, make no mistakes (at least I don't see any) and [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27%2By%27%2B1%2Fx+y%3D1%2Fx%5E2) finds the same solution. But in step $\int \frac{1}{x}\, \operatorname{d}x = \ln\left( x \right)$ you would neglect solutions for negative $x$ because $\int \frac{1}{x}\, \operatorname{d}x = \begin{cases} \ln\left( x \right), &\text{for}\, x > 0\\ \ln\left( -x \right), &\text{for}\, x < 0\\ \end{cases} = \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$.

So we would get:
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= x \cdot e^{-x} \cdot \int \frac{c_{1} \cdot e^{x}}{x^{2}} + \frac{e^{x} \cdot \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right)}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
\end{align*}
$}$$

##### Simplify The Integrals

We can even solve the integrals with special functions. First we say:
$$
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= x \cdot e^{-x} \cdot \int \frac{c_{1} \cdot e^{x}}{x^{2}} + \frac{e^{x} \cdot \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right)}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
y\left( x \right) &= x \cdot e^{-x} \cdot \left( \int \frac{c_{1} \cdot e^{x}}{x^{2}} + \frac{e^{x} \cdot \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right)}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x + x_{1} \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= x \cdot e^{-x} \cdot \left( \int \frac{c_{1} \cdot e^{x}}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x + \int \frac{e^{x} \cdot \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right)}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x + c_{2} \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= x \cdot e^{-x} \cdot \left( c_{1} \cdot \int \frac{e^{x}}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x + \int \frac{e^{x} \cdot \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right)}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x + c_{2} \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= x \cdot e^{-x} \cdot \left( c_{1} \cdot \underbrace{\int \frac{e^{x}}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x}_{I_{1}} + \underbrace{\int \frac{e^{x} \cdot \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right)}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x}_{I_{2}} + c_{2} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

###### Solving $I_{1}$

Let's solve $I_{1}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
I_{1} &= \int \frac{e^{x}}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x \tag{Partial Integration}\\
I_{1} &= -\frac{e^{x}}{x} - \int -\frac{e^{x}}{x}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
I_{1} &= -\frac{e^{x}}{x} -- \int \frac{e^{x}}{x}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
I_{1} &= -\frac{e^{x}}{x} + \int \frac{e^{x}}{x}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
I_{1} &= -\frac{e^{x}}{x} + \operatorname{Ei}\left( x \right)\\
I_{1} &= \operatorname{Ei}\left( x \right) - \frac{e^{x}}{x}\\
\end{align*}
$$

*For reference see [here](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=e%5Ex%2Fx%5E2).*

MAXIMA also finds $I_{1} = \Gamma\left( -1,\, -x \right)$.

Here $\operatorname{Ei}\left( \cdot \right)$ is the [Exponential Integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html) and $\Gamma\left( \cdot,\, \cdot \right)$ is an [Incomplete Gamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html).

###### Solving $I_{2}$

Let us use the taylor series of the exponential around $x = 0$ aka $e^{x} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{k!} \cdot x^{k} \right]$:
$$
\begin{align*}
I_{2} &= \int \frac{e^{x} \cdot \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right)}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
I_{2} &= \int \frac{\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{k!} \cdot x^{k} \right] \cdot \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right)}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
I_{2} &= \int \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{k!} \cdot x^{k - 2} \cdot \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right) \right]\, \operatorname{d}x\\
I_{2} &= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \int \frac{1}{k!} \cdot x^{k - 2} \cdot \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right)\, \operatorname{d}x \right]\\
I_{2} &= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \int x^{k - 2} \cdot \ln\left( \left| x \right| \right)\, \operatorname{d}x \right]\\
I_{2} &= \begin{cases} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \int x^{k - 2} \cdot \ln\left( x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x \right], &\text{for}\, x > 0\\ \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \int x^{k - 2} \cdot \ln\left( -x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x \right], &\text{for}\, x < 0\\ \end{cases}\\
\end{align*}
$$

We know $\int x^{n} \cdot \ln\left( \pm x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x = \frac{x^{n + 1} \cdot \left( n + 1 \cdot \ln\left( \pm x \right) - 1 \right)}{\left( n + 1 \right)^{2}}$ (for reference see [here](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=x%5En%20ln%28x%29) and [here](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=x%5En%20ln%28-x%29)).

So:
$$
\begin{align*}
I_{2} &= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{k!} \cdot a_{k}\left( x \right) \right]\\
\end{align*}
$$

where $a_{k}\left( x \right) = \frac{x^{n + 1} \cdot \left( n + 1 \cdot \ln\left( \pm x \right) - 1 \right)}{\left( n + 1 \right)^{2}}$ for $k \ne 1$ and $a_{1}\left( x \right) = \ln\left( x \right) \cdot \ln\left( \pm x \right)$.

Wolfram|Alpha simplifys this with:

[image: ...]

wehre $\operatorname{_{3}F_{3}}$ is a [Generalized Hypergeometric Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html) and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html).

Answer (score 0):

$$\ddot{y}+\dot{y}+\frac{1}{x}y=\frac{1}{x^2}$$
It's funny how you performed the integration by parts. I liked it. You can also integrate the DE this way:
$$x\ddot{y}+x\dot{y}+y=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$x\ddot{y}\color{red}{+\dot y-\dot y}+x\dot{y}+y=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$(x\ddot{y}\color{red}{+\dot y)-\dot y}+(x\dot{y}+y)=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$(x\dot{y})'-\dot y+(xy)'=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$(x\dot{y}- y+xy)'=\frac{1}{x}$$
Integrate both sides then for $x >0$:
$$x\dot{y}-y+xy=\ln {x} +C_1$$
This is a first order DE.
$$x\dot{y}+(x-1)y=\ln {x} +C_1$$

Comment: I can’t see how you were able to integrate the LHS without obtaining the Antiderivative of y. Can you explain please! Edit: never mind I see the product rule lol.

Comment: I added more lines is it more clear now ? @Person